# Remove commas from the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, counter

I want to change the date format by removing the commas.

I cannot access the html content
    
    var d = "Friday, 20 November, 2015, 2015, Sunday, 22 November, 2015"
    var res = d.replace(/,(?=\s+\d+)/g, "");
    document.write(res);

#### When

Friday, 20 November, 2015 - Sunday, 22 November, 2015
 09:00 -  17:00
GMT Time

```
                        <ul class="icons">

                        <li>
                            <a id="lnkAddCal" href="javascript:void(1);" style="text-decoration: none">
                                <img src="/g/images/details-calendar-large.png" title="Add to Calendar" alt="Add to Calendar"><span style="display:block">Add to Calendar</span>
                            </a>
                            <p id="tdCal" style="position:relative;display:none;">                                
                            </p>
                        </li>

                        </ul>

                <input name="planner" value="" type="hidden">
                <input name="title" value="" type="hidden">
                <input name="start" value="" type="hidden">
                <input name="end" value="" type="hidden">
                <input name="loc" value="" type="hidden">
                <input name="desc" value="" type="hidden">
                <input name="createdate" value="" type="hidden">
        </div>
```

I have no idea how can I do it without modifying the content page.

Please help.

Comment: Split your comma separated string, and join then again like you want.

Comment: Will it always in given pattern ? if yes i can give u simple js code to achieve your aim.

Comment: *the content page*? What are you talking about? Please [edit].

Comment: Where is _""Friday, 20 November, 2015, 2015, Sunday, 22 November, 2015" "_ generated , rendered within `html` at Question ?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is to use a regex like below. Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate https://jsfiddle.net/8srprLxu/

```
var str= "Thursday, 19 November, 2015 , Saturday, 21 November, 2015 ";
res = str.replace(/[, ]+/g, " ");
res = res.replace("2015", "2015,");
```

Comment: I was just about to post this. If the space before the comma separating the dates isnt a mistake and thats how the string is formatted, then this is your answer.

Comment: you have removed all ", "

Comment: Its giving an alert and if remove alert it doesn't work. Do I need t insert jquery lib also?

Comment: @RohitMehra you dont need jquery. See updated jsfiddle, which only removes the relevant commas

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald I am not that good in javascript. I can see it works with alert but i dont want it in alert. I want i use this script and  it remove the commas from the relevant sections. Thanks

Comment: @RohitMehra ok, well then you can remove the ```alert```, the function of that is just to show you that it works. How do you want to display this on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers) `x(?=y)`

> Matches x only if x is followed by y

match comma `,` only if comma followed by 1 or more space `\s+` followed by 1 or more digit `\d+`

```js
var d = "Thursday, 19 November, 2015, Saturday, 21 November, 2015"
var res = d.replace(/,(?=\s+\d+)/g, "");
document.write(res);
```